# For Ignite Persistence, how to control maximum data size on disk?

Tags: ignite

How can I limit maximum size on disk when using Ignite Persistence? For example, my data set in a database is 5TB. I want to cache maximum of 50GB of data in memory with no more than 500GB on disk. Any reasonable eviction policy like LRU for on-disk data will work for me. Parameter maxSize controls in-memory size and I will set it to 50GB. What should I do to limit my disk storage to 500GB then? Looking for something like maxPersistentSize and not finding it there.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct parameter to limit the complete disk usage occupied by the data itself. As you mentioned in the question, you can control in-memory regon allocation, but when a data region is full, data pages are going to be flushed and loaded on demand to/from the disk, this process is called page replacement.

On the other hand, page eviction works only for non-persistent cluster preventing it from running OOM. Personally, I can't see how and why that eviction might be implemented for the data stored on disk. I'm almost sure that other "normal" DBs like Postgres or MySQL do not have this option either.

I suppose you might check the following options:

- You can limit WAL and WAL archive max sizes. Though these items are rather utility ones, they still might occupy a lot of space  [[1]](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/native-persistence#wal-archive)
- Check if it's possible to use expiry policies on your data items, in this case, data will be cleared from disk as well [[2]](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/expiry-policies)
- Use monitoring metrics and configure alerting to be aware if you are close to the disk limits.

Comment: Redis-on-flash allows control of total in-memory + disk size. I think a similar option will be useful for Ignite too. Expiry policy and monitoring will help.  Thank you!